# TortoiseSVN Pre-Commit Hook on Windows Server

Tags: tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook, svnlook

We're using TortoiseSVN which is installed on the client machines I'm trying to setup a pre-commit hook to force comments on commit in our TortoiseSVN repository. There are posts everywhere about how to set it up using svnlook but I can't find it anywhere in my install. Am I missing something? Is there some sort of TortoiseSVN server program I need to install?

Comment: The pre-commit hook needs to be installed on your SVN server. Not on a client machine. You already have an SVN server, somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so through batch script, but there is a more easier solution for this.

Go to Svn Properties, and you will find a pop-up window.
Click on "New button" and Select "Logsizes". Again you will see a small pop-up window.
There you can enter the minimum log size, maximum log size etc..

I hope it would work for you.